# Zend Framework : Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching, frameworks

I am just learning Zend Framework. I created a simple Zend_Form and when I submitted the form I got following error:

```
An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:

Message: Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually
Stack trace:

 - 0 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Cache\Backend.php(197): Zend_Cache::throwException('Could not deter...')
 - 1 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Cache\Backend\File.php(123): Zend_Cache_Backend->getTmpDir()
 - 2 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Cache.php(153): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)
 - 3 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('File', Array, false, false)
 - 4 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Locale\Data.php(314): Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File', Array, Array)
 - 5 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Locale\Format.php(808): Zend_Locale_Data::getList('en_US', 'day')
 - 6 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Locale\Format.php(1118): Zend_Locale_Format::_parseDate('12/12/2010', Array)
 - 7 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Date.php(4765): Zend_Locale_Format::getDate('12/12/2010', Array)
 - 8 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Validate\Date.php(175): Zend_Date::isDate('12/12/2010', 'MM-DD-YYYY', NULL)
 - 9 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Form\Element.php(1395): Zend_Validate_Date->isValid('12/12/2010', Array)
 - 10 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Form.php(2252): Zend_Form_Element->isValid('12/12/2010', Array)
 - 11 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\localhost\zfprojects\zf_cms\application\controllers\BugController.php(30): Zend_Form->isValid(Array)
 - 12 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Controller\Action.php(513): BugController->submitAction()
 - 13 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('submitAction')
 - 14 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
 - 15 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
 - 16 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
 - 17 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\localhost\zfprojects\zf_cms\public\index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
 - 18 {main}
```

Request Parameters:

```
array (
  'controller' => 'bug',
  'action' => 'submit',
  'module' => 'default',
  'author' => '7676',
  'email' => 'ankur_gupta555@yahoo.com',
  'date' => '12/12/2010',
  'url' => 'http://blogs.antarjaal.in/takneek/?p=1354',
  'description' => 'tytytyty t',
  'priority' => 'low',
  'status' => 'new',
  'submit' => 'Submit',
)
```

System config:

- Windows 7
- IIS 7.5
- PHP 5.3
- Zend Framework 1.11.4

Comment: If any of the answers below solved your problem, please accept them by ticking the checkmark icon below the voting buttons. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it says

```
"Please specify a cache_dir manually"
```

So do that.

Example from Reference Guide:

```
$frontendOptions = array(
   'lifetime' => 7200, // cache lifetime of 2 hours
   'automatic_serialization' => true
);

$backendOptions = array(
    'cache_dir' => '/path/to/cache' // Directory where to put the cache files
);

// getting a Zend_Cache_Core object
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core',
                             'File',
                             $frontendOptions,
                             $backendOptions);
```

Equivalent when using the Cache Resource Plugin:

```
resources.cachemanager.database.frontend.name = Core
resources.cachemanager.database.frontend.customFrontendNaming = false
resources.cachemanager.database.frontend.options.lifetime = 7200
resources.cachemanager.database.frontend.options.automatic_serialization = true

resources.cachemanager.database.backend.name = File
resources.cachemanager.database.backend.customBackendNaming = false
resources.cachemanager.database.backend.options.cache_dir = "/path/to/cache"
resources.cachemanager.database.frontendBackendAutoload = false
```

Reference:

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.backends.html#zend.cache.backends.file
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.introduction.html
- http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html

Comment: Where should I write this code? is it possible to write this code in application.ini

Comment: It looks like PHP is not able to read/write in C:\Windows\Temp directory. What permission do I have to set to C:\Windows\Temp

Comment: It looks like PHP can write to that directory (try it out in PHP). It looks like is_writable() currently always returns false on the directory itself. You can however make a file in the directory using PHP, and when calling is_writable() on that file it will return true.

Comment: Config codes didn't work to me, neither specifying the cache_dir directory, seems like it still bugs for whatever reason...

Answer (score 2):

When looking at the Zend/Cache/Backend.php code, there are some alternatives to allow correct guessing of the cache_dir:

- Setting evironment variables like TMPDIR, TEMP or TMP
- set "upload_tmp_dir" in php.ini
- allow access to "/tmp" or "\temp"

At least that's how I read the code:

```
/**
 * Determine system TMP directory and detect if we have read access
 *
 * inspired from Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Abstract
 *
 * @return string
 * @throws Zend_Cache_Exception if unable to determine directory
 */
public function getTmpDir()
{
    $tmpdir = array();
    foreach (array($_ENV, $_SERVER) as $tab) {
        foreach (array('TMPDIR', 'TEMP', 'TMP', 'windir', 'SystemRoot') as $key) {
            if (isset($tab[$key])) {
                if (($key == 'windir') or ($key == 'SystemRoot')) {
                    $dir = realpath($tab[$key] . '\\temp');
                } else {
                    $dir = realpath($tab[$key]);
                }
                if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir($dir)) {
                    return $dir;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $upload = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');
    if ($upload) {
        $dir = realpath($upload);
        if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir($dir)) {
            return $dir;
        }
    }
    if (function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir')) {
        $dir = sys_get_temp_dir();
        if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir($dir)) {
            return $dir;
        }
    }
    // Attemp to detect by creating a temporary file
    $tempFile = tempnam(md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)), '');
    if ($tempFile) {
        $dir = realpath(dirname($tempFile));
        unlink($tempFile);
        if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir($dir)) {
            return $dir;
        }
    }
    if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir('/tmp')) {
        return '/tmp';
    }
    if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir('\\temp')) {
        return '\\temp';
    }
    Zend_Cache::throwException('Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should be helpful:

```
$_SERVER['TEMP'] =  realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/tmp');
```

Answer (score 2):

I was using 'memcached' instead of 'File', so my problem was a little bit different. I solved this by using:

```
        $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance ();
        $frontendOptions =
        array (
            'lifetime' => APPLICATION_ENV == 'development' ? '10' : '3600', 
            'automatic_serialization' => true
        );


    $backendOptions = array(
                        'servers' => array( array(
                            'host' => APPLICATION_ENV == 'development' ? '***' : '***', 
                            'port' => '***'
                        ) ),
                        'compression' => true
    );

    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory ( 'Core', 'Memcached', $frontendOptions, $backendOptions );

// Below is the fix for the problem! It appears that some validators / translates are caching
Zend_Locale::setCache($cache);
Zend_Translate::setCache($cache);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created "tmp" folder in the main directory it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Turn off/disable cache :) Why do you use it for simple app, when learning? There are more important things to learn ;)

Comment: I didn't used cache. But I have created a model with extends from Zend_Db_Table_Abstract. I think that is using cache. because when I submit the form it calls the model and the error displays.

Comment: Cache is never created unless you do that explicitely. You may have put that into application.ini.

Comment: Ahw, it actually comes from Zend_Date. Check if you have not set Zend_Date to use cache. Doesn't seem much like ZF to force you to use cache.

Answer (score 0):

you can put in .htaccess

```
SetEnv TEMP /tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this solve the problem , it solved it for me

```
Zend_Date::setOptions(array('cache' => $cache)); // Active aussi pour Zend_Locale
Zend_Translate::setCache($cache);
```

add it after setting your cache in the bootstrap.php

Comment: And the var `$cache` comes from where?