# Message: cache_dir must be a directory

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

Hello people I have some problems with Zend Framework.
 I first got the following message:
Message:
 Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually.

I searched google and found this post: [Zend Framework : Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651276/zend-framework-could-not-determine-temp-directory-please-specify-a-cache-dir)

I read it and now when I fill in the form I get the following error:
 
(Everywhere where I put .. in the error means the domain.)
Message: cache_dir must be a directory

```
- #0 /home/daan/domains/../library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(154): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir must ...')
 - #1 /home/daan/domains/../library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(121): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/domains/daan.h...')
 - #2 /home/daan/domains/../library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)
 - #3 /home/daan/domains/../library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('File', Array, false, false)
 - #4 /home/daan/domains/../library/Zend/Locale/Data.php(307): Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File', Array, Array)
 - #5 /home/daan/domains/../library/Zend/Locale/Format.php(796): Zend_Locale_Data::getList('nl_NL', 'day')
 - #6 /home/daan/domains/../library/Zend/Locale/Format.php(1106): Zend_Locale_Format::_parseDate('16-02-2013', Array)
 - #7 /home/daan/domains/../library/Zend/Date.php(4763): Zend_Locale_Format::getDate('16-02-2013', Array)
 - #8 /home/daan/domains/../library/Zend/Validate/Date.php(175): Zend_Date::isDate('16-02-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY', NULL)
 - #9 /home/daan/domains/../library/Zend/Form/Element.php(1391): Zend_Validate_Date->isValid('16-02-2013', Array)
 - #10 /home/daan/domains/../library/Zend/Form.php(2135): Zend_Form_Element->isValid('16-02-2013', Array)
 - #11/home/daan/domains/../application/controllers/BugController.php(27): Zend_Form->isValid(Array)
 - #12 /home/daan/domains/../library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(513): BugController->submitAction()
 - #13 /home/daan/domains/../library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(289): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('submitAction')
 - #14 /home/daan/domains/../library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
 - #15 /home/daan/domains/../library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
 - #16 /home/daan/domains/../library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
 - #17 /home/daan/domains/../public_html/index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
 - #18 {main}
```

Application.ini:

```
resources.cachemanager.configFiles.frontend.name = File
resources.cachemanager.configFiles.frontend.customFrontendNaming = false
resources.cachemanager.configFiles.frontend.options.lifetime = false
resources.cachemanager.configFiles.frontend.options.automatic_serialization = true    
resources.cachemanager.configFiles.backend.name = File
resources.cachemanager.configFiles.backend.customBackendNaming = false
resources.cachemanager.configFiles.backend.options.cache_dir = APPLICATION_PATH      "/../tmp"
resources.cachemanager.configFiles.frontendBackendAutoload = false
```

Initcache:

```
 protected function _initCaching() {
$frontend = array(
'lifetime' => $time,
'automatic_serialization' => true
);
$backend = array(
'cache_dir' => sys_get_temp_dir(),
);
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('core', 'File', $frontend, $backend);
Zend_Registry::set('cache', $cache);
```

}

Folder Structure:
.htpasswd
application
awstats
library
logs
public_ftp
public_html
tmp

Comment: Please edit your question to include your cache configuration

Comment: @TimFountain I don't understand your question do you mean my application.ini I'm following a book, I'm new to Zend

Comment: Yes, the parts of application.ini that relate to the cache. Or if you have an _initCache() function in your bootstrap class, that.

Comment: Do you have a 'tmp' folder within your application? Where are you wanting the cache files to be written to?

Comment: @TimFountain I have a tmp folder at the place APPLICATION_PATH "/..tmp/" I want the files to be written there.

Comment: @TimFountain Still cant get it to work, I updated the post with the folder structure.

Comment: Folder structure looks okay. You are positive that tmp is a folder and not a file?

Comment: @TimFountain I'm absolutely sure. I now can fill in the form again but I get this error again: Message: Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually

Comment: @TimFountain Thanks I fixed it because of you and liyakat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**cache_dir must be a directory :**

This problem came generally when you move your code to another host or server . There are mainly two solution for this problem

1 -  Make sure your cache directory is writable or you can make writable to var folder of magento

but sometimes this situation does not work so here is the alternate solution. Go to this location lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/
and open file.php file you’ll see the code something like this

```
protected $_options = array(
        'cache_dir' => null,
        'file_locking' => true,
        'read_control' => true,
        'read_control_type' => 'crc32',
        'hashed_directory_level' => 0,
        'hashed_directory_umask' => 0700,
        'file_name_prefix' => 'zend_cache',
        'cache_file_umask' => 0600,
        'metadatas_array_max_size' => 100
    );
```

**change this code as below**

```
protected $_options = array(
        'cache_dir' => '/var/www/html/webkul/magento/tmp',
        'file_locking' => true,
        'read_control' => true,
        'read_control_type' => 'crc32',
        'hashed_directory_level' => 0,
        'hashed_directory_umask' => 0700,
        'file_name_prefix' => 'zend_cache',
        'cache_file_umask' => 0600,
        'metadatas_array_max_size' => 100
    );
```

assign path of cache_dir as per your configuration .

Comment: 'cache_dir' => path is your server path you need modify it as per your server path did you check ?

Answer (score 0):

May be Zend is not able to find your cache directory. Try to se this in Bootstrap.php like this

```
protected function _initCache() {
    $frontend = array(
        'lifetime' => $time,
        'automatic_serialization' => true
    );
    $backend = array(
        'cache_dir' => sys_get_temp_dir(), /**automatically detects**/
    );
    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('core', 'File', $frontend, $backend);
    Zend_Registry::set('cache', $cache);
}
```

Comment: That Doesn't work @chandresh_cool. I can't even open the form now I get this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'cache_dir must be a directory' in 
Even though I chmodded it to 777

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `_initCaching` function from your bootstrap, you shouldn't have this and the application.ini entries as they are both trying to setup the same thing (but using different cache locations).

Your cache dir is set to `APPLICATION_PATH "/../tmp"` - i.e. a folder called 'tmp' at the root of your application (NOT in the application folder). Are you 100% sure that your tmp folder exists at this location? If so, you could try changing the application.ini configuration to use a full path instead:

```
resources.cachemanager.configFiles.backend.options.cache_dir = "/home/daan/domains/whatever/tmp"
```

just to see if that fixes the problem.

If you still can't get it working please post more information about the file structure of your application.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of this question is that open File.php file and change the path of the tmp folder.
This issue mostly comes when you tranfer your site from one server to another. When you transfer the site then the path of the tmp folder doesn't changed to the the new one. So edit the file.php and change the path of the tmp folder.

Answer (score 0):

[magento root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd6kF.png)

Creating "tmp" file in the magento directory solved this error for me.
I was able to access admin easily

Answer (score 0):

assign full path for your cache directory. For example,

```
'cache_dir' => '/var/www/html/var/cache1',
```

Answer (score 0):

Change path in `/install/config/`, edit file `vfs.php` and put new path name.

Answer (score 0):

One of the causes for this problem in CentOS/RedHat could be Selinux.
I got rid of this issue by just disabling Selinux

Edit the `/etc/selinux/config` file and set the SELINUX to `disabled`.