# Zend_Cache default cache_dir in application.ini

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching

On my server I have multiple virtual hosts, I run on them several applications based on ZF 1.12. When caching data (with Zend_Cache_Backend_File), each project saves files in /tmp.

The problem is there are some name and access rights problems. Running project2 I get this error:

Warning: fopen(/tmp/zend_cache---internal-metadatas---Zend_LocaleC_de_DE_currencynumber_)

and that is because the file was made by project1 running on separate virtual host.

So I would like to define separate folder for each project's cached data, something like this:

/tmp/porject1

/tmp/project2

The best way IMO would be to do this using application.ini - so I tried this:

```
resources.cachemanager.database.backend.name = File
resources.cachemanager.database.backend.customBackendNaming = false
resources.cachemanager.database.backend.options.cache_dir = "/tmp/project1"
```

But it isn't working - the data is still saved in /tmp - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You tried to clean the cache before do the change? $yourCacheManangerObject->clean(Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL);

Comment: I will answer with question :) Is database in resources.cachemanager.database.backend.name the cache manager object? If it is so I wouldn't know how to access it. The problem described by me occurs even if I don't use my own zend_cache objects (/zend_cache---internal-metadatas---Zend_LocaleC_de_DE_currencynumber_ is made by ZF itself).

Comment: No, backend.name is the type of "backend cache". The CacheMananger object is setted on the Zend_Registry. Use Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Cache_Manager') to access it.

Comment: Doing this in my bootstrap in _initRequest() I get nothing (it isn't already set). Maybe I asked my question not specific enough: I would like to be able to set the path for ZF cached data which has directly nothing to do with my application (is not set by my application but ZF itself, like: zend_cache---internal-metadatas---Zend_LocaleC_de_DE_currencynumber_ or zend_cache---internal-metadatas---Zend_LocaleC_de_DE_currencysymbol_EUR)

Comment: Hmm, try this `$_SERVER['TEMP'] = realpath('/tmp/project1');` and give a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7418320/1331554) question

Comment: That seems to work - thank you ;) Important hint: I had to chmod /tmp/project1 to 777.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the Zend/Cache/Backend.php code, there are some alternatives to allow correct guessing of the cache_dir:

- Setting evironment variables like TMPDIR, TEMP or TMP
- set "upload_tmp_dir" in php.ini
- allow access to "/tmp" or "\temp"

Then `$_SERVER['TEMP'] = realpath('/tmp/project1');` will solve your problem.

Remember to change the permission to 777 in the cache folder